# How does WebKit handle html5 download attribute?

Tags: html, qt, webkit

I want to download plain text with the new HTML5 attribute `download` of an `<a>` tag.

The HTML code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>    
  <body>
    <a id="a_tag" download="hello.txt" href="data:text/plain,abc">download txt</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works under FireFox 32 and Chrome 37 but not under IE 11 and Qt 5.2 (WebKit)

Is it possible to get this website to work with WebKit (Qt)? Are Blops the way to go?

**Edit:**
I figured out that WebKit is mainly from Apple and in Qt 5.2 Html5 or at least the download attribute is not supported.
My workaround is to use my own mime-type and handle the unsupportedContent Exception.

Comment: http://qtweb.net/ uses Qt 4.8 and WebKit to do a lot.  I ported the QtWeb project to Qt 5.2: https://github.com/peteristhegreat/QtWeb .  It still doesn't handle every possible web page, but it is pretty good.  It behaves a lot like Konqueror or ReKonq.  I haven't built the newer one with a static build yet, and it still requires plugins for running some kinds of web content.

Comment: Also the tabbed browser example in Qt Creator shows off the limitations/strengths of the Qt Web Kit really well.

Comment: So what does it mean now? Is it possible that Qt can handle "download"? Or can I handle a thrown unsupported link exception?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: @phyatt: your site shows the capabilities of the browser but not for WebKit with Qt...